# As capture the token that came through the head and send it to a function that I created myself?

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I'm trying to customize the Magento API Engine 2.
I would like to know if there is any time of the request, before arriving at webapi.xml to capture the token that came through the head and send it to a function that I created myself?
If yes, how and where can I do this?

Comment: $this->userContext->getUserId(); from this vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/ParamOverriderCustomerId.php

Comment: From above you can fetch Token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a possibility:

```
use Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request;

$header = $this->request->getHeader('Authorization');
```